2019 Macbook Pro early model Ubuntu Wireless Driver Install - Broadcom code [14e4:4488] (rev 4)
I recently decided to install Ubuntu on my 2019 early-model Macbook Pro. I'll drop some commands down below so you can see what the issue might be or what I need to install to actually use wifi. (I'm very new to all of this so excuse me if I forget to list something, please do ask if I did.
I don't even see the option of selecting a wifi network in my settings, only a Network tab and a Bluetooth tab.
(This code wasn't in the Broadcom list)

lspci -vnn | grep Network

showed:
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4377b Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4488] (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4377b Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0870]
01:00.1 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4377b Bluetooth Controller [14e4:5fa0] (rev 04)

and

iwconfig

showed:
lo        no wireless extensions.

enx9405bb1092a3  no wireless extensions.

Thanks a lot in advance, Noah.

Post URL from terminal for sudo dmesg |egrep -i 'brcm|firm'|nc termbin.com 9999
